# How to integrate google-maps in a vaadin page?

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, vaadin

I want to embed `google-maps` inside an existing `vaadin` webpage.

Problem: vaadin is written in java, so no `html` or `javascript` lines are coded.

There is an example on how to integrate maps using a static webpage: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" />
  </body>
</html>
```

As you see, this requires `<script>` stuff inside the page.

Question: how can I include those script content using vaadin? Plus how could I then pass the geocoordinates dynamically to the javascript function?

(I don't want to use any vaadin addon for this, as I simple just want to show the map).

Comment: Have you seen how they do it on their demo page? http://demo.vaadin.com/parking/

Comment: I get the following error: `Ooops...
You accessed Parking with a browser that is not supported. Parking is meant to be used with modern WebKit based mobile browsers.` My page is ment to be a webpage accessed with a desktop browser mainly.

Comment: Ah. How about this then? http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#foundation/execute-javascript

Comment: I know I can force execute a JS command. But I need something where I can put the whole JS script stuff, then call it by passing lat/lng.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom component in vaadin, and call the javascript code in the constructor of your custom component. This is easier said than done, so here's how you should be doing it:

Vaadin-UI page:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        /****************************************************
         * Create instance of custom component and set an id
         ***************************************************/
        Map mapobject = new Map();
        mapobject.setId("mapob");
        ..
        ..
        ..
        ..
       }
```

Then create a new java class with the name `Map.java` (your component)
This class should be something like this:

```
import com.vaadin.annotations.JavaScript;
import com.vaadin.annotations.StyleSheet;
import com.vaadin.ui.AbstractJavaScriptComponent;

@JavaScript({ "myscript.js", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"})
@StyleSheet({ "mystyle.css" })

//Extend AbstractJavaScriptComponent
public class Map extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent {

    float param1=123;
    float param2=456;
    public Map() {
       callFunction("myfunction",param1,param2); //Pass parameters to your function
    }

}
```

Now, the last step is to create your js and css files which you have linked.

Create --> myscript.js and mystyle.css files

Define all your styling in the css as it is

In your JS, define your function as follows:

```
window.your_package_name_Map = function() { //Put correct package name

      this.myfunction = function(latitude, longitude) {     //Accept the parameters
         var map;

            //mapob is the id of your component
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapob"), { 
            zoom: 8,
            center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude}
              });
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    }
        };
```

This should do it. I hope I haven't missed anything

Comment: Some questions on this approach: Is the `window.*` required in the JS class? And what is `callFunction("myfunction");`?

Comment: I tried the following, but the alert is not shown:

`demo_test_MapsComponent = function() {
 this.myfunction = function() {
  alert("hello");
 }
};`

Comment: yes, the window. is essential and probably that is why you are not getting your alert.

Comment: Also tried it with `window.demo_test_MapsComponent`, but no alert is shown.

Comment: callFunction() is a java function which calls a Javascript function defined within scope. myfunction is just a name for the function you will define in the JS file. You have defined it as this.myfunction=function{} in your JS

Comment: Sorry, I probably missed somthing. It works now, both with and without the `window` prefix. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anyways the gmaps script function above just does not show anyhing. No map is displayed unfortunately...

Comment: Did you set the id for your component and pass the same in the getElementById function ?

Comment: I had forgotten to put double quotes around mapob in the getElementById function. Kindly correct that in your code if you haven't already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83314/discussion-between-parth-mehta-and-membersound).

Comment: The solution is to use the following url: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=initialize`

Answer (score -1):

I don't really see why you could not use the addon, so you should use that:

- [Google Maps Add-on](https://vaadin.com/addon/googlemaps-add-on)

Comment: Addons are often discontinued over time, plus I just need a plain map with no additional features. Therefore I certainly will not rely on a community addon.